Benefits of prefixing all package names in a private codebase?
Let's say a team has up a ROS 2 codebase for a robotics competition. If there is:

no intention of releasing the packages (ie. registering on rosdistro)
no intention of reusing code in another project

are there any benefits in prefixing all the package names?
For example, a team called my_team would commonly name their packages as such:

my_team_bringup
my_team_msgs
my_team_localization
my_team_vision
my_team_motion

All of the package names get fairly long, and can be a bit of an inconvenience when build with colcon up to / above a specific package. Are there practical downsides to just dropping the prefixes, such that the package names are just:

bringup
msgs
localization
vision
motion

